# Can I use an Arduino and GSM breakout board for triangulation?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

IS there a way for me to use cell towers to triangulate my location with an Arduino Uno and GSM breakout board? if so how?

Comment: What sort of accuracy are you after? If you're thinking within a set group , then no as the signal is too variable; if you're thinking in square miles + then yes! Just walking through the 'shadow' of a building will cause major signal level fluctuations.

Comment: A directional antenna with "steering" will be of some value in some situations, but 'city canyons' may render this useless (or worse :-) ).

Comment: While there are obviously limitations, the key question is if your module exposes cell identity and signal level information via an interface you can use.  And it would seem more useful if it can expose info for additional cells it is aware of, beyond the one it is actually using and when not engaged in handover.

Comment: what if i used a gps module? How accurate could I be?

Comment: new gps modules are really good, but the accuracy depends on many variables. number of satelites, weather. worst case can be kilometres, best case can be less than 1 meter... But if you have the choice go for gps. It does what excactly what you want...